# Get the duplicate records in MySQL by comparing 2 columns from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables namely degree_occupations and ideal_jobs. I need to get the unmatched records in the degree_occupations table and vice versa (in two different MySQL queries). First I'll show how the data looks like in both tables.

**degree_occupations**

```
id|deg_code|occ_code
1 |BVS   |SSB
2 |CAC   |SSC
3 |CBP   |SSM
4 |CBP   |SCH  
5 |CBP   |SSB
6 |DEF   |SSE
7 |PAR   |SSM
```

**ideal_jobs**

```
 id|deg_code|occ_code|dept_code
  1|BVS     |SSB     |AAB
  2|CAC     |SSC     |IND
  3|CBP     |SCH     |GOM
```

The result data what I expect is something like this,

**degree_occupations**

```
id|deg_code|occ_code|found_in_ideal_jobs
1 |BVS     |SSB     |1
2 |CAC     |SSC     |1
3 |CBP     |SSM     |0
4 |CBP     |SCH     |1
5 |CBP     |SSB     |0
6 |DEF     |SSE     |0
7 |PAR     |SSM     |0
```

if the value is found in ideal_jobs table return value should be 1 else it should return 0.
I need a MySQL query to get the following data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a left join based on the two columns in `degree_occupations`, and then a `case` expression to check if there's a matching record in `ideal_jobs`:

```
SELECT    d.id, d.deg_code,
          d.occ_code,
          CASE WHEN i.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS found_in_ideal_jobs
FROM      degree_occupations d
LEFT JOIN ideal_jobs i ON d.deg_code = i.deg_code AND d.occ_code = i.occ_code
```